# Ruby Hide Console

Tags: ruby, winapi, console, hide

I am attempting to make a game written in Ruby using the Gosu library (http://www.libgosu.org/) but when I run the game, a console also shows. How do I make sure the console is hidden from the start? thanks in advance, ell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run with with rubyw.exe or use the extension *.rbw?